# Bootstrap 3 datepicker checkin checkout

Tags: asp.net, webforms, datepicker, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to implement a bootstrap 3.x datepicker solution for my website.  I am using 
[eternicode Datepicker and Bootstrap3 checkin checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19864398/eternicode-datepicker-and-bootstrap3-checkin-checkout) solution as found here but can't seem to get it to work.

Firebug shows on errors on page load of:

**TypeError: checkin.date is undefined**

and when datepicker is being selected

**TypeError: chechout is undefined**

using bootstrap/3.0.3 and jquery-2.0.3. Any ideas what i'm doing wrong here...?

Thanks

```
var nowTemp = new Date();
var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

var checkin = $('#dp1').datepicker({

    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        return date.valueOf() >= now.valueOf();
    }
}).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
    if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
        var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
        checkout.setValue(newDate);
        checkout.setDate(newDate);
        checkout.update();
    }
    checkin.hide();
    $('#dp2').focus();
}).data('datepicker');
var checkout = $('#dp2').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        return date.valueOf() > checkin.date.valueOf();
    }
}).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
    checkout.hide();
}).data('datepicker');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check out my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FTpYk/2/) that has a working version.

I also ran into trouble invoking `checkin.date.valueOf()`. Retrieving the date of a datepicker should rather be done by invoking `checkin.datepicker("getDate").valueOf()`.

If you have any questions, let me know!